# h2,ormlite CLOB<->String Conversion

Tags: h2, ormlite, clob

I need to store a long string value with h2. How can I do this?
When i'm trying to insert a long string an exception is thrown which says that the values is to long "CONTENT VARCHAR(255): "STRINGDECODE...".

I read that CLOB should be used but i dont have any idea how to use it right.

How does the table definition need to look like?
At the moment I'm simply using a String declaration.

```
@DatabaseField
String content;
```

And how could i convert a String to a CLOB and can I stil use the String content; declaration? Or is there a possibility to raise the VARCHAR size to the maximum?

Comment: Sometimes you need a beer to find a solution ;) @DatabaseField (dataType = DataType.Long_string)

Comment: For others reading this question, you should add that as an answer, and then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to store a long string value with h2. How can I do this?

[ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) has a [long-string type](http://ormlite.com/docs/long-string) which persists data using the `LONGVARCHAR` JDBC type.

> How does the table definition need to look like?

Something like:

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.LONG_STRING)
String content;
```